# How to manipulate current task's Activity back stack?

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, android-task

Currently I have 3 `Activity` classes A, B and C.

Activity A is a `singleTask` while other has the default launch mode.
Consider a case: the user is first in A, then starts B, and then starts C.

The back stack now is ABC.

Next, the user starts A again.

The back stack now is A, but what I would like to be achieved is ABCA.

I know not setting `Activity` A to be `singleTask` can have a back stack : ABCA.
But I really need the Activity A to be the same instance.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: already look at the docs and see no way to archive this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stipulated two conditions:

> what I would like to be achieved is ABCA.

and

> I really need the Activity A to be the same instance.

These two conditions are mutually contradictory. Absolutely.

What you want is impossible.

That is all.

Answer (score 0):

`That is not possible.`

if you want to open existing activity then

launch your activity as

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: that will lead to BCA, not ABCA

Comment: yes. As you (@Y.S.) told that  his conditions are mutually contradictory. So that I gave this answer.

Comment: ok, great, no problem :) ... i merely pointed out that this won't get the OP the result they want.

Comment: btw can we reorder a activity to back instead of front?

Comment: No, Instead use same thing to another activity to which you want to order Front..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need `singleTask` and not `singleTop` ? Could you describe why do you need it `singleTask` ?

Comment: Because I want A to be a single instance.

Comment: then maybe you should consider launching it with the same params and not make it singleTask, like @Y.S. said it's a bit contradictory what you want to achieve

Comment: Then consider the case of ABCA'BCA'', how can I jump back to A' or A immediately and clear the back stacks to ABCA' or A ?

Comment: the answer for that would be CLEAR_TOP flag http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: CLEAR_TOP need to be used together with startActivity(indent), but how can you specific which A or A' is being start and CLEAR_TOP?

Comment: well, how else would you "jump"?

Comment: just call finish() on Resume of each Activity until I reach the targeted Activity?
Or its is okay to store a reference to each activities? So that I can explicitly call finish() on those activities I would like to close.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. It will lead to unexpected behavior. This is the reason why the intent flags were introduced to play around with the activity/task stack. You can find more info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html